# Access Denied Issue

Tags: maven-3

Trying to use Maven from the command line. Have setup the setting.xml proxy -

```
    <proxy> 
       <id>optional</id>
       <active>true</active>
       <protocol>http</protocol>
       <username></username>
       <password></password>
       <host>access.lb.xxx.org</host>
       <port>80</port>
       <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
```

From cmd screen tried running the command - mvn archetype:generate -X

Getting errors like -

```
    ...
    Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: 
    Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:pom:2.0  
    from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Access denied to:     
    http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release   
    plugin/2.0/maven-release-plugin-2.0.pom, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap  
    (WagonRepositoryConnector.java:951) ...
```

Can't figure out if the proxy setting is correct? Is there a workaround to go pass the proxy? Or any other way to get me going to create a simple maven project at the least?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you having empty username/password ? Do you have no password or didn't you wrote it down here for security reason ;-)

Comment: Are you sure your proxy settings is correct - for instance is the proxy server running on port 80?